# Choice between 1-dimensional and 2-dimensional array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, data-structures

I'm implementing the `Chessboard` class to represent the chessboard. I've to implement the **transformations** (reflections and rotations) on the chess board possible.

The possible transformations includes the combination of:

```
 1. Vertical Reflection
 2. Horizontal Reflection
 3. Diagonal Reflection
```

Thus, we've **8** possible transformations for chess board.

There are **64** squares on the Chessboard numbered [0..63].

Thus, to represent the total resulting values after the transformations is 8*64 (No.of Transformations *  Chessboard_Size).

There are two fundamental ways to represent the **transformed_board** using Arrays:

```
One-Dimensional Array with transformed_board[8*64]
Two-Dimensional Array with transformed_board[8][64]
```

**Questions:**

```
Which approach is better?
What are the pros and cons of each approach?
How will effect the performance with respect to time factor?
```

Comment: i will suggest you to choose two dimensional.. in this way you can track the move and cell as well.. but in case of one dimension tracking the both will be little typical..!!

Comment: They are nearly the same in memory. But 2D array might be better because the index is more readable.

Comment: "I'm implementing the Chessboard class" ... Unless you really do OOP in C (which is a bit tricky), I suppose you have your tags wrong. Please verify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory layout is the same for both, so there isn't really any "real" difference whatsoever. It's just a matter if whether you want the compiler to do the offset calculation for you or not, so just go with the syntax you like better.